# PHP $GLOBALS vars are not accessible from another file

Tags: php

I need to store persistent login information across connections, pages and sessions, so I cannot use `$_SESSION`. I read the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) about `$GLOBALS`:

> References all variables available in global scope

and I tried this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
$GLOBALS["level"] = "user";
$GLOBALS["time"] = time();
header("Location: /session.php");
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
$time = $GLOBALS["time"];
$level = $GLOBALS["level"];

var_dump($time);
var_dump($level);
```

Output:

> NULL NULL

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I'm not using the global vars inside a function, so I'm in the "global" scope.

Comment: The value of `$_SESSION` is persistent across requests. `$GLOBALS` is just a regular global variable that ceases to exist when the current request completes. The feature you need can be implemented using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: If you want persistent data across various connections/users, you would need to use some sort of cache.  GLOBALS isn't the same thing.

Comment: Why downvotes if I didn't understand how it works? If I understood it I didn't ask the question.

Comment: @axiac, does `$_SESSION` is persistent also across different browsers?

Comment: @Mark No session is persistent across different browsers and that is actually a correct intended behavior.

Comment: @vivek_23, so how to have such a "global" variable? I need to allow one user at time, so I need to store the "session" information (level and time) where I can read them even if another user use a different browser.

Comment: @Mark Not sure what you are trying to achieve, is this per user or all users who are connected?

Comment: The data stored in `$_SESSION` is identified using a cookie. Technically it is not linked to the browser but for all practical purposed you can think it is. The cookie is stored in the browser so you can consider that the data stored in `$_SESSION` is linked to a particular browser that runs on a particular account of a particular computer.

Comment: @vivek_23, I'm trying to have a persistent variable server-side. So when any browser requests a page, I will retrieve the same information and I can grant or refuse the connection.

Comment: @Mark Use database then.

Comment: @vivek_23, wow, I didn't think I need a db only for a couple of vars! Anyway, if this is the only way your comment should be an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table in your database and handle your variables there. This way, you can get the same values for any request made from any browser. You can also create an empty file on server and store and retrieve data in JSON format. This is another possible option, but you will have to handle concurrency which can be tedious. So best option is go to with the database. To manage concurrency, you will have to start the transaction and commit like below:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table2 SET some_var=some_value WHERE some_type=some_integer;
COMMIT;
```

You can also `rollback` if there is any issue. This way you can ensure the [`ACID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html) properties of your data always between requests.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For me "This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script." was not so clear, because I understood anywhere in my script the `$GLOBALS` vars were availables. Thanks to the others for the downvotes.

Comment: @Mark Yes, global variables are available through out the script  but  they have their own instances for each HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

You redirect to `session.php` because of your header. You add no data to it, just a `Location` header. This is the same as if you would open example.com/session.php in your browser (so no data). The `$GLOBALS`
 resets every time you refresh the page, just like a normal variable.

Could it be you're looking for `include` ?

---

Also, try not to use globals. I suggest you read up on functions and use those pass around information

Comment: Yes, why the downvote? Strange.. For me your hint makes much sense